# how to I type an array comprehension in Julia when using a recursive function?

Tags: arrays, recursion, type-inference, julia

I am try to use Array comprehension with a recursive function:

```
groupBy=[x->get_ancestor_self(msr.dhaEdges[msr.cubeDef.hiers[x]][x], drillByMatched[x])::DimHierAttr for x in i]
println ("xxxxx: $(typeof(groupBy))")  --> #Array of Function
```

the resultant Array is and Array of Function (even if I type the array as follows)

```
groupBy=DimHierAttr[x->get_ancestor_self(msr.dhaEdges[msr.cubeDef.hiers[x]][x], drillByMatched[x])::DimHierAttr for x in i]
```

here is recursive function I am calling ....evenually is returns a DimHierAttr

```
function get_self_if_ancestor(dha::DimHierAttr, dh::DimHier) 
    if dha.dimHier == dh
        return dha
    elseif dha.parentDimHierAttr == nothing 
        return nothing
    elseif get_ancestor_self(dha.parentDimHierAttr, dh) == nothing
        return dha
    else
        return nothing
    end  
end
```

Any ideas on how to get this to infer (or can I annotate the type)  as Array{DimHierAttr,1}???

Answer (score 1):

As a first try, drop the anonymous function.  I.e.,

```
groupBy=[get_ancestor_self(msr.dhaEdges[msr.cubeDef.hiers[x]][x], drillByMatched[x]) for x in i]
```